# pgAdmin4でエラーメッセージが文字化けする

Tags: postgresql, 文字化け, rhel

pgAdmin4からRHEL8.4上のPostgreSQL15.1へ接続しDBのバックアップを試みたところ、エラーが発生したのですが、エラーメッセージが文字化けしてしまいエラー原因が分かりません。文字化けを解消する方法をご教示いただきたいです。

【試したこと】
エラーメッセージを英語化すればよいかと思い、postgresql.confの設定を以下の通り変更、再起動してみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。

# lc_messages = 'ja_JP.UTF-8'
　lc_messages = 'en_US'

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]